# Retrieve data from either of table based on column value in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create table test
(
id int,
Name varchar(50),
ObjType varchar(50)
Typeval varchar(50)
)
```

I have 2 other tables named say tbl1 and tbl2

Based on value in ObjType in table "test", I have to retrieve column from tbl1 or tbl2. 
NOte: Column name i want to retrieve is not same in tbl1 and tbl2.

something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Objtype,id, typeval, 
 Desc = CASE WHEN objtype='abc' THEN 
                 SELECT col1 from tbl1 WHERE cond=id (col from table test) 
             WHEN objtype = 'xyz' THEN 
                 SELECT cola from tbl2 WHERE crit = id (col from table test)
```

Can any body guide me

Comment: Any relationship between test,tb1 and tbl2?. If so join and then pull from either tbl1 or tbl2 using CASE based on objtype

Comment: tbl1 and tbl2 is not related. basically test has column with id of master data, i need to fetch description from master table. we have more then one master table to store data

Comment: @Saravanan If the tables are not related, which is the fetching logic? Without a relation it won't work, unless tbl1 and tbl2 have only 1 row each and you always fetch that one... but this is another problem.

Comment: I have mmentioned the relation in my query itself. the id column is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating a CTE by joining table t1 and t2

```sql
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT col1, objtype 
  from tbl1

  UNION

  SELECT col1, objtype 
  from tbl2
)

SELECT 
  Name, Objtype, id, typeval, 
  (
    SELECT Col1 
    FROM CTE C 
    WHERE C.ObjType = t.ObjType
  ) as Description
FROM Test t
```

Thanks for all who posted their valuable comments

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the union statement.

```
SELECT t.objtype as objtype, t1.col1 as fieldvalue 
FROM test t LEFT JOIN tbl1 t1 ON t.cond= t1.id
    WHERE t.objtype = 'abc'
UNION ALL
SELECT t.objtype as objtype, t2.cola as fieldvalue 
FROM test t LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t.crit= t2.id
    WHERE t.objtype = 'xyz'
```

It needs some changes to work but it may help you.

Comment: i modified this query as i had two columns as of same need.. anyways thanks